# NextGen Gallery not allowing me to display the_excerpt();?

Tags: excerpt, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I have a site hosted locally that has a plugin called NextGen Gallery, I have over 4,000 images within galleries in this plugin, so I definitely need it.

When the plugin is active, it will not let me use the_except(); in my index.php file.

I know its the plugin because I went through each plugin manually and made sure it was that plugin that was affecting it.

I really need to get this sorted ASAP, so if anyone has a clue on what's in the plugin that could be breaking the excerpt function, please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know *how* the plugin prevents you from using `the_excerpt()`.

I guess the reason *why* the plugin does not want you to use `the_excerpt()` is as follows: `the_excerpt` creates an excerpt from an article by cutting it after the first 50 words. This might cut in the middle of a `<script>...<script>` fragment, which NextGEN had inserted in order to display a gallery as slideshow.